# Creating a synthetic control with pooled cross-sectional data

Tags: r, regression, survey, cross-section, synthetic-controls

Is there a way to create a synthetic control using pooled cross-sectional data, rather than a panel?

I'm analyzing a staggered reform and, so far, the methods I've found require having a panel: Ben-Michael, Feller & Rothstein 2020 (augsynth), Callaway & Sant'Anna 2019 (did), Xu 2017 (gsynth), and potentially also Robbins, Saunders, & Kilmer 2017 (microsynth).

Comment: What's the unit of observations in your data?

Comment: Individuals within a household. My data set is made up of 22 pooled cross-sections, where each subsequent year a quarter of it is resampled, so I don't have the same households every year.